# Passing line from file as argument to puts?

Tags: ruby, shell

is it possible to do something like this?

```
File.open('/etc/logo', 'r') do |f|
  f.each_line{ |line| puts line }
end
```

But I don't want the content of lines to be printed as text but rather figured out as arguments to the `puts` command. To make myself clear, this is the example /etc/logo:

```
"\e[34m" + 'BLUE COLOR' + "\e[31m" + 'RED COLOR'
```

I want to separate the ASCII logo from my code. Thank you for your ideas.

Comment: Hmm, it seems I solved it :)

Comment: Answer is to use 'eval', like this: puts eval line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
File.open('/etc/logo', 'r') do |f|
    f.each_line{ |line| eval "puts #{line}" }
end
```

Don't let anyone edit that file.

---

If you want a more secure way to do it, try this:

```
File.open('/etc/logo', 'r') do |f|
    f.each_line{ |line| 
        puts line.gsub(/\\e/, "\e")
    }
end
```

For this, you should use a file like:

```
\e[34mBLUE COLOR\e[31mRED COLOR
```

This just replaces the escaped \e with the real character.

Comment: Thank you for your comment on code injection. Logo file has root:root permissions and program using it is run on TTY1. So, only case someone can inject code is if he has root account, and then it's useless to modify logo to inject code - because attacker already has root :)